# Manually edited credentials.yml.enc by mistake, but after undoing changes I get

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wasn't aware that I couldn't manually edit `credentials.yml.enc` so I tested some changes and after they didn't work I tried undoing my changes with `ctrl+z`.

Essentially the file is the same as it currently was, however I'm getting an error when starting the server: "ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)"

I've tried `rails credentials:edit` just see if the file opens but I get the error `Couldn't decrypt config/credentials.yml.enc. Perhaps you passed the wrong key?`

#### Overview of the application

This is a small API for my friends' app. I'm still working on it, so it's not yet in use. Can you recommend anything I can do, even if it means discarding and recreating both credentials.yml.enc as well as the `master.key`?

### Solution

I deleted both `master.key` and `credentials.yml.enc` and generated new ones with `rails credentials:edit` and that solved it. Thank you!

Comment: discard and recreate both credentials.yml.enc as well as the master.key -- then store them in a password manager or other secure file system.

Comment: _Essentially the file is the same as it currently was_ - probably not, because you have some issue. Do you use Git? If so,  you can restore it, because this file is tracked